# remove type declaration from XML while serialize

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I need to get clear xml without any `namespace` and `type` declarations. Here is the serialized xml:

```
<placeBetRequest p1:type="PlaceBetRequestTeamed" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</placeBetRequest>
```

Need to someway configure XmlSerializer to set it don't add any attributes but only mine (if I set them with `[XmlAttribte]`
the clean xml need to looks like this:

```
<placeBetRequest>
...
</placeBetRequest>
```

Here is my serialization method:

```
public static string XmlConvert<T>(T obj, params Type[] wellKnownTypes) where T : class
{
    var emptyNamepsaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
    XmlSerializer serializer = wellKnownTypes == null
        ? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
        : new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), wellKnownTypes);
    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, emptyNamepsaces);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using regex

```
string input = 
    "<p1:placeBetRequest p1:type=\"PlaceBetRequestTeamed\" xmlns:p1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
    "</p1:placeBetRequest>";

    string pattern = @"(?'prefix'\</?)(?'ns'[^:]*:)";
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "${prefix}");
```